# Add X days to a Received Date but Exclude Weekends/Holidays from a Date Table

Tags: db2

I hope someone can help with a calculation that I am having trouble developing.

I am developing a report in a DB2 database that I need to add "X" number of days to a "RECEIVED" date/time when an order comes in between X and Y; but exclude Weekends and Holidays to add to the received date. I have created a [TBLCALENDAR] that lists the Weekends and Holidays (Example below); and from this, I want to ADD X number of days to a "DUEDATE"

```
tblCalendar]
DATE                   DAYOFWK  DAY      HOLIDAY
1/19/2019                  7    Saturday    
1/20/2019                  1    Sunday  
1/21/2019                  2    Monday       YES
```

So, for example 1, if I have an order that is placed on 1/18/2019 at 4:01pm; the due date should be 1/23/2019 at 11:00am.

Example 2: if I have an order that is placed on 1/18/2019 at

Conditions are:
Previous Date 4:01pm to Current Date 11:00am = Due Date should be + "X" business days by 11:00am
If order received Current day by 4:00pm = Due Date should be + "X" business days by 4:00pm

I have tried to reference the tblCalendar to get the [Received] date/time and add X number of days based off of an order, but it's not functioning the way I have hoped.

I have used the following code...but it doesn't exclude Weekends or Holidays when adding the specified number of days or have my order time requirement to take into account previous day after 4:00pm to current date of 11:00am:

```
  RECEIVEDDATETIME + 2 days as DUEDATE;
```

I have also used the below code to reference TBLCALENDAR to find the # of holidays and weekend days in a date range:

```
         ( SELECT COUNT (*) FROM TBLCALENDAR AS C WHERE C.HOLIDAY = 'YES'
            AND C.DATE BETWEEN TBLORDERS.RECEIVEDDATETIME 
            AND TBLORDERS.DUEDATETIME) +
            (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM TBLCALENDAR 
            WHERE DAYOFWK IN (1,7)
            AND DATE BETWEEN TBLORDERS.RECEIVEDDATETIME 
            AND TBLORDERS.UPLOADTIME) AS NONWORKINGDAYS
```

Expected field output

If order was received between 1/17/2019 4:01pm to 1/18/2019 10:59am = 1/23/2019 11:00am
If order received Current day by 4:00pm 1/18/2019 3:59am= 1/23/2019 by 4:00pm.

```
RECEIVEDDATETIME    DUEDATE
1/17/2019 4:01pm    1/23/2019 11:00am
1/18/2019 10:00am   1/23/2019 4:00pm
```

Comment: Can you please verify the last example - if it is received by 10 am why is it due to 4 pm? In the text above you divide the day basically in 4pm. - 11 am (off hours) and 11 am to 4pm (work hours) if I got it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution without the time logic.

```
with tblCalendar(DATE, DAYOFWK, DAY, HOLIDAY) as (values
  (date('2019-01-19'), 7, 'Saturday', '')     
, (date('2019-01-20'), 1, 'Sunday', '')
, (date('2019-01-21'), 2, 'Monday', 'YES')
, (date('2019-01-22'), 3, 'Tuesday', '')
, (date('2019-01-23'), 4, 'Wednesday', 'YES')
, (date('2019-01-24'), 5, 'Thursday', '')
, (date('2019-01-25'), 6, 'Friday', '')
, (date('2019-01-26'), 7, 'Saturday', '')
)
, mytab (RECEIVEDDATE, DAYS2ADD) as (values 
  (date('2019-01-19'), 2)     
, (date('2019-01-20'), 2)
, (date('2019-01-21'), 2)
, (date('2019-01-22'), 2)
)
select m.*, t.date as DUEDATE
--, dayofweek(date) as DAYOFWK, dayname(date) as DAY
from mytab m
, table
(
  select date
  from table 
  (
    select 
      date
    , sum(case when HOLIDAY='YES' or dayofweek(date) in (7,1) then 0 else 1 end) over (order by date) as dn_
    from tblCalendar t
    where t.date > m.RECEIVEDDATE
  )
  where dn_ = m.DAYS2ADD
  fetch first 1 row only
) t;
```

The idea is to enumerate each day of the calendar after the `RECEIVEDDATE` (1-st parameter) starting from 1 with the following logic: the number of each day increases by 1 if it's non-holiday non-weekend day (the `sum(...) over(...)` expression).
Finally, we select a date with the corresponding number of days needed to add (2-nd parameter).

Comment: This code looks promising when testing it with different dates; however, how can I add it to my sql statement to reference my tblCalendar without the value statement in the code?                                                                                                                 SELECT ORDERDATE, RECEIVEDDATE AS DUEDATE (your code referencing the calendar table against the date) from tblOrders

Comment: Got it:) Thank you for your help. I was so busy yesterday that I didn't take time to fully analyze your example thoroughly. I have rewritten to suite my needs and so far with the dates I've plugged in, it's working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Solution idea:
Your tblCalendar is a good idea but I recommend to add the working day information instead of (only) flagging the holidays and weekends. The problem with the "off days" are that after you have figured out how many of them are in the period from your receive date to the receive date + X days you cannot easily add them because there could be other "off dates" in that perios again.

By numbering all the work days you could identify the workday which is closest (equal or bigger) to the receive date. Retrieve its number and add the X days to that number. Retrieve the date that has this work day number and you are fine.
The time logic should be built before that all because it could add another day to the X days.